# Decision tree only predicts one class

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am fitting decision tree on the following dataset:

```
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data
```

And following is my code:

```
balance_data=pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data",
                           sep= ',', header= None)

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
balance_data = balance_data.apply(le.fit_transform)
X = balance_data.values[:, 0:5]
Y = balance_data.values[:,6]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 100)

#using Gini index
clf_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", random_state = 100,
                               max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)

clf_gini.fit(X_train, y_train)

#using Information Gain
clf_entropy = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy", random_state = 100,
 max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)
clf_entropy.fit(X_train, y_train)


#Gini prediction
y_pred = clf_gini.predict(X_test)
y_pred

#IG prediction
y_pred_en = clf_entropy.predict(X_test)
y_pred_en
```

In both cases Gini Index and IG, the output is following:

```
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,])
```

Is there problem with training? Moreover how can I convert this numeric value to string value.

Edit1: I calculated the accuracy and it says 71. Is there a possibility that the only problem is in the display of the output?

Answer (score 5):

#### Your dataset is unbalanced

Given that your data looks like this:

```
       0      1  2  3      4     5      6
0  vhigh  vhigh  2  2  small   low  unacc
1  vhigh  vhigh  2  2  small   med  unacc
2  vhigh  vhigh  2  2  small  high  unacc
3  vhigh  vhigh  2  2    med   low  unacc
4  vhigh  vhigh  2  2    med   med  unacc
```

And that your target variable is column 6 `Y = balance_data.values[:,6]`. A quick look into the the target variable distribution leads to conclude that your dataset is unbalanced.

In fact, when starting a new machine learning project, one of the main tasks to do is checking whether your dataset is unbalanced. This can be done by counting the distribution of the observations of the target variable values.

Since your data is a pandas dataframe, your get the values distribution as follows:

```
In [46]: balance_data.iloc[:,6].value_counts()
Out[46]: 
unacc    1210
acc       384
good       69
vgood      65
Name: 6, dtype: int64
```

As you can see, the dataset contains mainly observations with the target value `unacc`, 70% to be accurate:

```
In [49]: 1210/1728.
Out[49]: 0.7002314814814815
```

As you mentioned, the accuracy of your model is around 71% which corresponds to the percentage of target value `unacc` from the overall dataset.

There are several techniques to overcome this problem, check the following links for detailed tutorials on that:

- https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/
- https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-classification-problem/